# Generating a PDF using prawn sometimes results in damaged PDF

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pdf-generation, prawn

I'm creating a multi-page PDF that contains a table with 7 columns.

When I create the PDF on my development computer (Mac OS X 10.8, ruby 1.9.2, Rails 3.2.6) it downloads and renders correctly.

If I create the PDF on my staging server I get the following error message when I try to view it in Preview 'It may be damaged or use a file format that Preview doesn’t recognize.'

If I create the PDF on my production server it works correctly.

I've tried removing all the columns in the table and adding them back in one at a time to see which is causing the problem but this results no obvious cause.

Thinking it may be a table width problem I've tried changing it to landscape and reducing the font size but still no difference.

Even though it works on the production server I want to get to the bottom of it in case it starts happening there too. Also my client won't be able to sign off the updates if they cannot be tested on staging.

Here is the code

```
@locations.each do |location|
    modules_marked = 10 # this is calculated in the actual code
    exams_marked = 10 # this is calculated in the actual code

    total_delegates += CourseDelegate.for_location(location).count
    total_modules += modules_marked
    total_exams += exams_marked

    entry = []
    entry << location.name[0..5]
    entry << location.division.name
    entry << location.operating_unit_number
    entry << location.purchase_order
    entry << CourseDelegate.for_location(location).count
    entry << modules_marked
    entry << exams_marked

    entries << entry
end

table(entries, :header => true, :width => bounds.width) do 
    row(0).font_style = :bold
    row(entries.count - 1).font_style = :bold

    cells.border_width = 0.1
    cells.border_color = "808080"

    cells.size = 8
    column(1).width = 60
    column(2).width = 60
    column(3).width = 50
    column(4).width = 50
    column(5).width = 50
    column(6).width = 50
    column(0).align = :left
    column(1).align = :left
    column(4).align = :center
    column(5).align = :center
    column(6).align = :center
end
```

Even replacing all the entries with hard coded single letters still causes the crash to occur.

UPDATE:
I should mention that when I view the damaged PDF file in a text viewer it looks as if the file just stops midway through and is missing the end which is why it is not displaying in any PDF viewer.

Comment: Andrew, it feels like you might be looking in the wrong place. There might be gems / libraries that your application only has access to in production mode. Also, it could be a production only config variable?

Comment: Removing just 2 columns (any 2 it seems) from the table results in it working. I'm not sure how that would be down to gems etc.

Comment: Looking at the difference between the two environments will help you diagnose the problem. The main difference between production and dev are gems and configs. I know it's not intuitive but you might be surprised.